# How can I compare 2 columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have 2 columns in excel, I need to search each of the values in the first column in the second one and have each value that exists in both them written/marked.

How do I even start this?

Comment: Assuming your two columns are A and B, then a formula in `C1`: `=COUNTIF(B:B, A1)`. This will return a number representing the number of times `A1` was found in column `B`. If it finds `0` then there was no match. Copying this down for every value in column `A` will give you your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might go for conditional formatting, based on this formula:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$7,0)))

=MATCH(A2,B$2:B$7,0) // is also fine
```

- `Match()` searches for a matching result. If not found, an error is shown.
- Beware: you check for cell "A2", then "A3", then "A4", ..., but the range where you search ("B$2:B$7") does not change, hence the dollarsigns).
- `NOT(ISERROR(...))` basically gives `TRUE` in case of found, and `FALSE` in case not. This will be the basis of the conditional formatting.

**Edit:**
According to [Mayukh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya) and verified afterwards, the `NOT(ISERROR(...))` or `ISNUMBER()` construction is not even needed: you can just use `=MATCH(A2,B$2:B$7,0)` as a formula for your conditional formatting.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Instead of NOT(ISERROR(MATCH())), it can be ISNUMBER(MATCH())  Just an FYI, slightly less typing and one less function.

Comment: @Dominique Sir , Scott Craner Sir, we dont even need those `ISNUMBER()` or `NOT()` `ISERROR()` since conditional formatting will ignore the `#N/A` values, only `=MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$7,0)` this will do. Sir, see here [MATCH()](https://imgur.com/a/pDPz8dJ)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya: thanks a lot for your comment, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Dominique glad to share and learn.